# Using Slice on string in java script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop, split, slice

Hi I have string like :

```
[{"list":"Gross Motor Skills""value":"8"}{""list":"Sorting""value":"8"}
 {""list":"Grouping""value":"8"}{""list":"Drawing""value":"8"}
 {""list":"Observations""value":"6"}{""list":"Writing""value":"7"}]"
```

and I want to remove all extra stuff and get it into an array as :

```
Gross Motor Skills 8
Sorting 8 
etc.
```

I tried splice and split but I failed to get anything out of it.Can anyone help me to get it ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What should be the structure of the output array?

Comment: string is JSON?

Comment: Fix the "string" to be valid JSON and then check the methods of [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/)

Comment: There are bunch of errors on your data structure definition. Aditional " and others.

Comment: The original data looks like JSON, there is a missing `"` at the start and some duplicate `"`. If you could edit the post to add the correct data it will be easier to answer.

Comment: yes that is a JSON string but I can not change the structure because I'm fetching it and I dont have control over the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With proper array/objects, you could use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) for the values.

```js
var array = [{ list: "Gross Motor Skills", value: "8" }, { list: "Sorting", value: "8" }, { list: "Grouping", value: "8" }, { list: "Drawing", value: "8" }, { list: "Observations", value: "6" }, { list: "Writing", value: "7" }],
    result = array.map(o => Object.values(o));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

> and I want to remove all extra stuff and get it into an array as :
>
> ```
> Gross Motor Skills 8
> Sorting 8 
> etc.
> ```

Use `map` and `join`

```
var output = arr.map( s => s.list.concat( s.value ) ).join( "\n" );
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [{
    "list": "Gross Motor Skills",
    "value": "8"
  }, {
    "list": "Sorting",
    "value": "8"
  },
  {
    "list": "Grouping",
    "value": "8"
  }, {
    "list": "Drawing",
    "value": "8"
  }, {
    "list": "Observations",
    "value": "6"
  }, {
    "list": "Writing",
    "value": "7"
  }
];
var output = arr.map( s => s.list + " - " + s.value ).join( "\n" );
console.log( output );
```

Or if the array is required as an output then omit `join`

```
var output = arr.map( s => s.list + " - " + s.value );
```

Comment: I tried doing this and works fine when the array is defined in the Var . But m getting input in terms of response like : var arr = response[i].list ; how can I map this ?

Comment: How does the response look like?

Comment: [{"list":"Gross Motor Skills""value":"8"}{""list":"Sorting""value":"8"}
 {""list":"Grouping""value":"8"}{""list":"Drawing""value":"8"}
 {""list":"Observations""value":"6"}{""list":"Writing""value":"7"}]"
This is the response. All in one line as string.

Comment: Commas are missing, this is not a valid JSON. You need to fix this at the source itself.

Comment: I fixed the source and added commas. But when i assign response to var arr and then tried to map it, it returns undefined - undefined in console.

Comment: @Aniket How does the final JSON string look like then? Please share the same.

Comment: after few tries I was able to convert it to an array like : 0
:
"[{list:Gross Motor Skillsvalue:8"
1
:
"list:Sortingvalue:8"
2
:
"list:Groupingvalue:8"
3
:
"list:Drawingvalue:8"
4
:
"list:Observationsvalue:6"
5
:
"list:Writingvalue:7}]"

Comment: after few tries , I was able to solve the problem. Thanks for the help @ gurvinder372